# How I can create multiple join with DQL

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

How I can create multiple join with `DQL` , something like this in `sql`:

```
SELECT t,c,u FROM `user` AS t
LEFT JOIN (`contract` AS c, `car` AS u) 
  ON (t.id = c.`user_id` AND u.id = c.`unit_id` AND u.name = 'audi')
WHERE t.email = 'test@example.com';
```

**Solve problem by another way, create sub-query:**

```
    $query = $this->createQueryBuilder('user')
        ->addSelect(
            array('contract', 'car')
        )
    ;
    $query->leftJoin(
        'user.contracts',
        'contract',
        Expr\Join::WITH,
        'contract.id IN (
               SELECT contract2.id
               FROM DataBundle:User user2
               INNER JOIN user2.contracts contract2
               INNER JOIN contract2.car car2
               WHERE user2.email = :email AND (
                    contract2.status = :status1 OR contract2.status = :status2
               ) AND car2.name = :name
        )'
    );
    $query->leftJoin(
        'contract.car',
        'car'
    );

    $query->where('user.email = :email');
```

Maybe will be useful for someone.

Answer (score 1):

See [article](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine1/en/latest/en/manual/dql-doctrine-query-language.html) for multiple join example :

**DQL JOIN Syntax:**

```
[[LEFT | INNER] JOIN <component_reference1>] [ON | WITH] <join_condition1> [INDEXBY] <map_condition1>,
[[LEFT | INNER] JOIN <component_reference2>] [ON | WITH] <join_condition2> [INDEXBY] <map_condition2>,
...
[[LEFT | INNER] JOIN <component_referenceN>] [ON | WITH] <join_conditionN> [INDEXBY] <map_conditionN>
```

Comment: Thanks, it's was help me to get answer

Answer (score 0):

You will end up with something like this:

```
SELECT user,contract,car 
FROM user AS user
LEFT JOIN user.contract AS contract
LEFT JOIN contract.car AS car
WHERE user.email = 'test@example.com' AND car.name = 'audi';
```

Obviously you need to define your entities and set up the relations properly.  I'd suggest following the example in the documentation and then working your way through a test case.

Please note that the use of abbreviations (t,c,u) for aliases has been declared a war crime by the United Nations and will be punished severally.

Comment: Ok, I will create alias better:) sorry. Your answer not help me, sorry.